# Correct way of allowing a user to create a new choice in a choicefield

Tags: python, django, model

I need my it so that users are able to create extra Role's if it is not within the TYPES_CHOICES tuple. I have it so that if the role is not available they may select 'Other' and then create an Extra Role.

I would like it so that they can only pick a choice from the tuple xor create an extra role and select that role. Would I do the validation check inside models.py? Or when I create the form?

```
class ExtraRole(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 20)

    def __unicode__(self): 
        return self.name

class Role(models.Model):
    TYPES_CHOICES = (
        ('PLAYER', 'Player'),
        ('CONDUCTOR', 'Conductor'),
        ('COMMITTEEMEMBER', 'Committee Member'),
        ('LIBRARIAN', 'Librarian'),
        ('TUTOR', 'Tutor'),
        ('ACCOUNTANT', 'Accountant'),
        ('PRESIDENT', 'President'),
        ('CHAIRMAN', 'Chairman'),
        ('SECRETARY', 'Secretary'),
        ('OTHER', 'Other')
    )
    type = models.CharField(_('Type'), max_length = 20, choices = TYPES_CHOICES)
    extra_roles = models.ForeignKey(ExtraRole)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.type
```

Comment: I am pretty sure you will need some JavaScript for this one. Your HTML must be modified dinamically when 'Other' field is selected. And this must happen without pressing a submit button, therefore, wtihout your view to pass through a POST or GET. So a JavaScript code should check if you selected the 'Other' option.